# can't compile statically programs

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I am trying to build a cross-compiler for an ARM and not having success with Clang and LLVM, too much stuff to do to make my machine do its thing..
So, I went to the web page for LinuxKD, to get clang and LLVM to build correctly, which I have done and they work..
So, I went back to that same site, (LinuxKD) to find out How to build a cross compiler for ARM, and it uses "Crosstool-ng" which is fine with me.. I have loaded a later Version than is shown in the web site, He uses crosstool-ng-1.12.0 and I am using crosstool-ng-1.19.0...
So, it starts to do its thing after setting it up, but it comes with the following error:

```
[DEBUG]  Checking that gcc can compile a trivial statically linked program   (CT_WANTS_STATIC_LINK)
[DEBUG]    You may need to ensure that static libraries such as libc.a are installed on your system
[DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'x86_64-build_unknown-linux-gnu-gcc' '-O2' '-g' '-pipe' '/home/cctools/arm/.build/arm-unknown-eabi/build/test.c' '-static' '-o' '/home/cctools/arm/.build/arm-unknown-eabi/build/.gccout' 
[DEBUG]    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
[ERROR]    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Checking that gcc can compile a trivial statically linked program (CT_WANTS_STATIC_LINK)'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: CT_DoExecLog[scripts/functions@257]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@540]
[ERROR]  >>
```

My system is a Fedora 20, running on an I7 Asus..
It states that /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc  ,, 
Is -lc a program or a sub instruction of the Ld program, or is it something else ??
Or am I missing a program ?? Something like Glibc, which I have the latest for this Fedora 20 Linux..

Comment: What's unclear about `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc`? Do you have a libc in the path?

Comment: Which Path ?? do I put Libc in and is Libc different than Glibc, which is installed..

Comment: I don't understand why people give vague unclear answers and then I have to ask for clarification of what they are saying.. Instead of giving an answer that actually helps the person originally asking the question ..

Comment: I tried to install Libc using Yum,, as yum install libc .. Which states that there is no such program..

Comment: probably `glibc-dev` or `libc6-dev` or something like this.

Comment: I yummed glibc-devel, and tried it.. No change.. It states that --    [DEBUG]    You may need to ensure that static libraries such as libc.a are installed on your system,, Where do I check for Libc.a and If it is not there how do I put it there ??

Comment: I searched for libc.a and the search showed up nothing.. I assume its not there, so how is it created ???

Comment: I have installed glibc-static and now it passes that problem.. But, it breaks at the next test.. stating that it can't find -lstdc++, and after looking that up.. The Fedora site says I need Libstc++ ,, which I installed along with libstc++-devel.. but, it still doesn't see it..

Comment: [DEBUG]    ==> Executing: 'x86_64-build_unknown-linux-gnu-gcc' '-O2' '-g' '-pipe' '/home/cctools/arm/.build/arm-unknown-eabi/build/test.c' '-static' '-lstdc++' '-o' '/home/cctools/arm/.build/arm-unknown-eabi/build/.gccout' 
[DEBUG]    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Comment: I got it Solved ! I had to to install Both Glibc-static and libstdc++-static, which were NOT listed in the Fedora 20 repository.. Another search for lstdc++ found the solution on the Fedora site

Answer (score 3):

On Fedora 19 and 20, to statically compile C programs, you need to install the packages `glibc-devel` and `glibc-static`.

```
sudo yum install glibc-devel glibc-static
```

To show that it's working afterwards:

```
cat > hello.c <<'EOF'
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    puts("Hello, world.");
    return 0;
}
EOF

gcc -o hello hello.c -static
ldd hello
./hello
```

should print:

```
   not a dynamic executable
Hello, world.
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't have anything to do with *cross-compiling* statically linked programs for the ARM; I'm just trying to deal with the fact that the program you're trying to install is complaining that it can't compile a static binary for the machine it is running on.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `-lc` error in the linkage step was due to `libc.a` be an ELF 32bit, so not being able to link a 64bit compiled object.

```
check it with:<br>
"#file {build_path}/x86_64-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libc.a"  or<br>
"#file {build_path}/x86_64-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib/libc.so"
```